# Responsive Lists in SharePoint 2016 (on prem)

Tags: list, sharepoint-on-prem, pnp, responsive

I'm wondering if there is a nice way to make lists work with responsive design (for mobile and tablet views)?

I've been investigating this responsive framework from PnP for general page content, but not sure how to tackle lists.

I'm not using device channels or anything like that (and I'd prefer to). I'm using SP2016.

Any thoughts?